# Проверка для всего контролера в yii2

Tags: yii2

Как сделать проверку всего контролера на определённые параметры, а не для каждого action отдельно.

Что бы 100 раз не писать проверку на гостя.

Например

```
class NameController extends Controller {

    public function actionoIndex()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {    
            return $this->goHome();
        }    
     }

    public function actionOther()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {    
            return $this->goHome();
        }    
     }
 }
```

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте RBAC:

```
public function behaviors()
{
return [
    'access' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
        'only' => ['create', 'update'],
        'rules' => [
            // deny all POST requests
            [
                'allow' => false,
                'verbs' => ['POST']
            ],
            // allow authenticated users
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
            // everything else is denied
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'actions' => ['delete'],
                'roles' => ['admin'],
            ],
            //доступ в экшену удаления имеет только пользователь с ролью админ
        ],
    ],
];
}
```

В доке это описано.

Answer (score 3):

Определите в контроллере метод **beforeAction(){}** и в нем опишите всю интересующую Вас логику.

Этот метод вызывается перед вызовом определонного action контроллера.

Если это нужно для всех контроллеров - создайте между ними прослойку в виде контроллера, и наследуйтесь от него

Comment: Не очень понимаю тогда как проверить всех action в контролере в вашем варианте , когда я делаю проверку выдаёт ошибку на другой контролер.  public function beforeAction($action)
    {if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest or Yii::$app->user->identity->id_role_user !== 3) {

            return $this->goHome();
        }return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

Comment: beforeAction срабатывает перед вызовом любого action контроллера

Comment: Он ругается на другой контроллер public function actionIndex()
    {$searchModel = new Findsearchjur();
        $arrParams = array(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($arrParams, Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
 
       // var_dump($dataProvider); die();
 
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);}

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Я же не буду за Вас писать код. Я показал способ проверить для всех action контроллера что-либо. Дальше сами

Comment: Просто вы дали вариант который не работает.

Comment: https://webformyself.com/yii2-beforeaction/

Comment: Этот урок не подходит к данной задаче так как проверка проходит по конкретной странице а не по всему данному контролеру

Comment: Вы перечитайте формулировку своего вопроса: "Как сделать проверку всего контролера на определённые параметры, а не для каждого action отдельно"

Comment: Если определяется метод beforeAction в контроллере, он сработает перед вызовом КАЖДОГО action этого контроллера

Comment: Так он и не срабатывает перед КАЖДЫМ

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Controller.php#L242

Comment: Я тоже могу вам ссылок накидать, только это не решение которое вы предлагаете.

Comment: Сработал следующий код, кто будет редиректить имейте ввиду public function beforeAction($action)
    {
     

 if(\Yii::$app->user->isGuest or Yii::$app->user->identity->id_role_user != 3) {
   return \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('/')->send();        
     }
  return parent::beforeAction($action);
 }